# MongoDB Remote Backup and Restore

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I hope you can help me. It is a question that was asked before, but I have tried all solutions, and simply cannot get it right.

I have spend quite some time researching before posting this question. I have looked at the official MongoDB documents and many other blogs.

How can I make a DB backup/dump remotely, as well as restore that dumb locally?

This is what I have thus far:

**Running this from a new CMD prompt shell:**

```
C:\Users\Admin>mongodump --host 10.13.9.210 -d C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin --port 29039 --out /backup/mongodump-2015-11-13
```

I get this error:

```
2015-11-13T10:26:41.371+0200    error parsing command line options: expected argument for flag `/o, /out', but got option `/backup/mongodump-2015-11-13'
2015-11-13T10:26:41.371+0200    try 'mongodump --help' for more information
```

Secondly; how will I be able to restore this backup locally?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not a programming question, for which StackOverflow is for, Your question is about database administration and utilities. Ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. If it has not already been answered there already.

Comment: try putting double quotes around the path name

Comment: Thanks, Blakes. i have only now come across the dba.stacexchange.com forum. Do I remove my post here and re-post it there?

Comment: @onmyway yes, remove it here and post there. One thing to keep in mind: you will not be able to comment on DBA until you have gained 50 reputation points.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was moved and answered on [SE.DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120972/creating-a-mongodb-backup-dump-on-remote-server-via-local-cmd-shell).

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a dot at the start of the out path.
"./backup/mongodump-2015-11-13"
instead of 
"/backup/mongodump-2015-11-13"